# trying to read from a local json with json.decode function and doesn't work - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

For an unknown reason the json.decode(and jsonDecode) functions just don't work.

I'm trying to read a json file from the users phone but there is no error message or anything, its just keep getting stuck at the json.decode() line

```
void writeToFile(String key, String value){
   //jsonFile is a File
   Map<String, String> content = {key: value};
   if(fileExists){
      print('start decoding');
      Map<String, dynamic> jsonContent = jsonDecode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync());
      print('finish decoding');
      jsonContent.addAll(content);
      jsonFile.writeAsString(json.encode(jsonContent));
   }else{
     print('no file');
   }
}
```

Comment: add more info, what's the error? what's the input data?

Comment: when you call `jsonFile.readAsStringSync()` are you getting the json data in string?

Comment: Remove semicolon at the end of 3 row.

Comment: `Map<String, String> content = {key: value};;`   at the end of line 3 In your code there is an extra semicolon remove that, if that still doesn't resolve the issue post the error you are getting

Comment: please provide the value of `jsonFile.readAsStringSync()` ;)

Comment: what ever inside the local string, you can see the type of the key value where i create the map